# Using Elementary IO on an old MacBook Pro in dual boot mode

Tags: dual-boot, macbook

I would like to install Elementary IO on an old (2015) MacBook Pro, but at this time, I would also like to keep MacOS installed, along with all associated files.
I believe I can create a separate boot partition to run Elementary, but as I am a newbie to this, I want to make sure I don't lose any data or otherwise corrupt my disk.
Is there a resource which can guide me through this process as well as give me a good background on how I should think about configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Installing eOS on a 2015 MacBook Pro is great, as nearly everything works out of the box. I recently installed eOS 6 beta on a 13-inch 2015 MacBook Pro, and it works great. Dual-booting is also a great choice, as it makes updating firmware easy if/when necessary.

Since elementaryOS is based on Ubuntu, guides for dual booting Ubuntu should be directly applicable. Two guides I have found useful for dual booting Ubuntu on Mac are [LinuxNewbieGuide's installation guide](https://linuxnewbieguide.org/how-to-install-linux-on-a-macintosh-computer/) and a [YouTube video by Reed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bONsydLV3A).

I wrote up and posted [here](https://blog.senderolinux.com/2021/06/27/installing-eos-6-on-2015-macbook-pro-121/) the steps I used to install eOS 6 beta on a 2015 MacBook Pro. Everything worked well except the camera, which took some extra troubleshooting to get fixed.

Comment: You appear to be the author of the linked article. When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Thanks, edited accordingly.